# What are the differences between g++ version 4.0.0.8 and 4.3.2?

Tags: c++

What's the difference between g++ 4.0.0.8 and g++ 4.3.2? These two are the most common C++ compilers that I have seen used in various programming competitions.

I tried to google it, but found nothing.

Comment: Checkout in detail -> http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html

Comment: @DumbCoder thats a huge list.I just wanted to know if there are any major differences b/w these two.Most of the on line programming competitions like SPOJ have these two versions of C++, if there hadn't been any difference b/w them then SPOJ would have only the latter version(i.e latest one, as SPOJ have for other programming language compilers)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's really not such a 'huge list', considering you're interested in the C++ changes between the two.

4.0.0.8 is just a patch revision of 4.0, whose release notes are here: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.0/changes.html

4.3.2 is a patch revision of 4.3, whose release notes are here: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html

If you look at the differences between them, I think the following list covers the most important differences between GCC 4.0 and 4.3 that you would really care about.

**GCC 4.3.2 has (including changes from [GCC 4.1](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.1/changes.html) and [GCC 4.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.2/changes.html)):**

**[Experimental support for the ISO C++0x standard](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/cxx0x_status.html)** (that's a link)

- `long long` is now officially supported in C++ (though it was an extension provided in older GCC anyway)
- Template `extern` is supported
- Right angle brackets like you'd see in `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` are now supported (note the lack of a space between the two `>` at the end of the declaration).
- [experimental support for Variadic Template Arguments](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2242.pdf)
- [Static assertions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1720.html)
- and some others

**More TR1 library support**

- `<regex>` (gcc 4.3), `<random>` (gcc 4.2), and `<complex>` (gcc 4.2)

**C++ visibility handling has been overhauled. (GCC 4.2)**

> Restricted visiblity is propagated from classes to members, from functions to local statics, and from templates and template arguments to instantiations, unless the latter has explicitly declared visibility.
>
> The visibility attribute for a class must come between the class-key and the name, not after the closing brace.
>
> Attributes are now allowed for enums and elaborated-type-specifiers that only declare a type.
>
> Members of the anonymous namespace are now local to a particular translation unit, along with any other declarations which use them, though they are still treated as having external linkage for language semantics.

**An undocumented template extension was removed in GCC 4.2 (was deprecated in 4.1)**

> The (undocumented) extension which permitted templates with default arguments to be bound to template template parameters with fewer parameters has been removed. For example:

```
template <template <typename> class C>
void f(C<double>) {}

template <typename T, typename U = int>
struct S {};

template void f(S<double>);
```

> is no longer accepted by G++. The reason this code is not accepted is that S is a template with two parameters; therefore, it cannot be bound to C which has only one parameter.

---

**Additionally, check the [porting to GCC 4.3 guide](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/porting_to.html), where some important stuff is, like:**

**Backward compatible/deprecated headers have been removed.**

Mostly this means a bunch of pre-standard headers have been removed, like `<iostream.h>` (use the standard `<iostream>`), `<hash_map.h>` (use `<tr1/unordered_map>`) `<hashtable.h>` (use `<tr1/unordered_map>` or `<tr1/unordered_set>` depending on needs), etc. Again, not a big deal.

**Stricter enforcement of standards**

For example, the signature on `main`'s two-argument form must be correct.

**No duplicate function parameter names**

```
void func(int x, int x); // now an error
```

---

And there have been various bug fixes, as well as changes I don't think really affect how you'd write competition code (like removal/addition of new compiler flags), and removal of stuff like the `<?` and `>?` operators (ever used those?).

All in all I don't think the differences between the two will cause you much grief if you had to write code for both compilers.

Answer (score 0):

You are wondering about the difference between two different version of g++? It's two common version of GNU C++ compilers. Different Linux releases may have different version of g++ shipped with it. Like my current CentOS 5.5 has g++ 4.1.2 with it.

For you feature details, check the link in you comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 4.3.2 is newer then 4.0.0.8, it is more standard compliant. For details, you have to check documentation and release changes