# Difference between gcc-4.0.0-8 and gcc-4.3.2

Tags: c++, gcc

SPOJ and Codechef have both of them in list of accepted languages. What is the so big difference between them that they have to be distinguished?

Comment: you can check the gcc changelog for the difference http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html

Comment: But that doesn't cover thing changed in 4.1 and 4.2 plus I wanted BIG differences NOT ALL differences. But anyway, thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563340/what-are-the-differences-between-g-version-4-0-0-8-and-4-3-2/4565181#4565181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C++, they aren't binary compatible with each other, for one thing.

There's a lot of openmp function that arrived between 4.0 and 4.3 for another.

Answer (score 0):

All the changes between GCC major versions are described on each versions changes page:

1. Changes in [4.1](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.1/changes.html)
2. Changes in [4.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.2/changes.html)
3. Changes in [4.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html)
4. Changes in [4.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html)

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated above, I wanted some summary of the biggest changes.

Comment: @Dunemaster: There are many options: different languages and platforms that GCC supports make answering this question almost impossible..

Answer (score 0):

Application Binary Interface (ABI) has changed (meaning you cannot (reliably) link binaries from different versions together)